# How to use an unicode character instead of a background image?

Tags: css

I want to replace the `background-image:url(image.png)` by an Unicode character or icon like "\xxxxx" in css

How to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using pseudo elements?

I suggest using

```
:before
```

width z-index: -1;

Check my exmple here: https://jsfiddle.net/oyq47zsj/

I used "A" as background, but you can use any char

Comment: Great, or, if the OP wants the background to scale to the content (like background-size:contain), maybe something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/oyq47zsj/1/).

Comment: The other important part used here is the `content` key in CSS

Comment: Thanks Pawel & Mr Lister, I just did [something cool](https://jsfiddle.net/7w1b3yhg/27/) thanks to your fiddles :)

Comment: If you're trying to set the arrow for a dropdown menu, note that the :before and :after approach won't work in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

We could pass a SVG containing a `<text>`  as a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs), like so:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #272b2d;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 100 100'><text y='0.8em' font-size='100'></text></svg>");
  background-size: cover;
}
```